# #NAME? Error with Google Sheets Pivot Table Calculated Field

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, calculated-field

I looked this issue up and did not find any sufficient solution for myself.

I am trying to create a Calculated Field through Google Sheets Pivot Tables and I'm getting the #NAME? error.

To my best understanding I'm following the steps given to create the Calculated Field correctly and no where can I find an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet (with private information removed):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCtZceVYFaPEWh57TrMLyFS8e7vGXunf7EWIEHZmCpo/edit?usp=sharing

I've gone through all the steps to verify that my method is correct. None of those column headers have any spaces in them, so I don't need the ' ' encasing each word.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 13):

I figured it out. Funny how the universe works. It's like as soon as I was willing to ask for help, the answer came to me :).

The column headers themselves were in a number format (Accounting to be specific). Because the values of those columns were intended to be dollar amounts, I formatted the entire column to Accounting. In doing so, the header (which contained text) also became formatted as an Accounting value.

Because of the headers were in a number format, the Calculated Field was unable to match the text to the value in the header. What this means: When creating a Calculated Field with Google Sheets Pivot Tables, the values being entered are explicitly defined (and matched accordingly) by Google Sheets. Text is probably actually looked at as a string type where as numbers are looked at as numbers (which makes sense of course).

Solution: I changed the headers to a text format and the calculated field no longer threw the #NAME? error! Yay :)